# How to persist objects between classes

Tags: objective-c, class, properties

I have 6 categories that contain unique data; I have defined a class that  looks like this:

```
@interface ExportBookData : NSObject {

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *booksArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *builtFileList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *exportData;

@end
```

What I want to do is be able to instantiate the class ExportBookData, once for each category, and use that instantiated class throughout another class, having the data persist and be accessible between classes.

I have tried this code, but it doesn't do what I need:

```
ExportBookData *abe = [ExportBookData new];  
abe.abeBuiltFileList = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
abe.abeExportData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:abe.abeBooksArray.count];
```

***UPDATE***  The problem is in the addressing of the objects; I have categories named Abe, Balls, Comp, Caller, Hut, and House.  I want the class to have properties that can be addressed as Abe, Balls, etc.  I can't figure out how to do that with what I have defined.

I have looked through Google, but found nothing that answers my specific question.

Comment: To those who down voted this question:  how can I show research effort if I don't know enough to ask the question intelligently?  I have already looked at Google and found nothing that would help.

Comment: why doesn't it do what you need? you need to provide more details. show us where it fails.

Comment: "I want the class to have properties that can be addressed as Abe, Balls, etc. " Why do you need that? To put it another way, looking at your example, why do you need a property called `abeBuiltFileList`? Why not have a `builtFileList` that works no matter whether this thing was instantiated for Abe or for Balls? Obviously it's only going to be instantiated for _one_ of those, so you just need one `builtFileList` property.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to accomplish, but probably didn't explain myself very well... I wanted a class with the 3 properties, where I can create the 6 properties in one method, and use them in another method.

Comment: Properties can always be used in multiple methods; that's what a property _is_. A property is globally visible to all methods.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but it's the naming and subsequent addressing that has me confused...

Comment: But that's why I said don't use special-case naming.

Comment: Can you give me an example (I still don't grasp *exactly* what you are saying).  And the 6 "categories" with the properties will exist separately, so after creating them, I will process them in another method.

Comment: I don't grasp what _you_ are saying at all. It's as if you didn't know what object-oriented programming _is_ — and I know _that's_ not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate, encapsulate, encapsulate! Put the special knowledge *inside the class itself*.

Let's say you have an ExportBookData object that behaves differently depending which bookseller it uses. Then provide an initializer that takes a bookseller type:

```
ExportBookData *abe = [[ExportBookData alloc] initWithCategory:@"Abe"];
```

Okay, so now *this* instance of ExportBookData knows that its *behavior* should be Abe-type behavior. But no matter *how* an ExportBookData is initialized, its public *property* names will all be the same, e.g. `builtFileList` and `exportData`, so you'll then be able to refer to `abe.builtFileList` and this will be the *right* kind of list for an Abe.

Comment: That's it!  I'll work with it, now that I know what I need... Thanks Matt, I appreciate it very much.  SD

Comment: I should point out that it would be possible to go even further and use subclasses: that is, have an ExportBookData class that provides the general behavior and then an AbeExportBookData subclass, a BallsExportBookData subclass, and so on, each of which provides the _specialized_ behavior for that bookseller. Any time you see yourself doing a lot of "switching on category types" for a class, that's a bad smell for which the fix is using subclasses instead; looking at it another way, a subclass _is_ a switch, but at the structural level instead of the code-logic level.

Comment: Thanks for the info; in this case, each bookseller has a dictionary associated with it, and each dictionary has 2 string arrays, one of which rarely changes, the other contains strings indicating which books are to be further processed by the selling venues.  This app has been around for quite a few years as a Windows app, and re-wrote it for iOS, with much needed improvements.  Thanks again for your help, I truly appreciate it.  SD