# Encapsulation causing crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, encapsulation

I am trying to incorporate encapsulation into my app (for an explanation of what this code is supposed to do, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577373/how-to-persist-objects-between-classes))... this is the code in Class 'A':

.h file

```
@interface ExportBookData : NSObject {

@public NSArray *booksArray;
@public NSMutableDictionary *builtFileList;
@public NSMutableArray *exportData;
}

- (id)initWithCategory: (NSString*) booksellerID;

@end
```

This is the code for the .m file:

.m file

```
@implementation ExportBookData

-(id)initWithCategory: (NSString*) booksellerID  {

return (id)booksellerID;
}

@end
```

This is the beginning of the method in class 'B' (.m file) that uses the encapsulated data:

```
ExportBookData *abe = [[ExportBookData alloc] initWithCategory:@"ABE"];
abe->builtFileList = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; <- crash on this line
abe->exportData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:abe->booksArray.count];

if(cbvABE.checked)  {
```

I'm getting the following error on the 2nd line of code as indicated:

[image]

Since I'm a noob using encapsulation, I don't see what I've done wrong.  I have followed several examples which are similar to my code;  what am I doing wrong to cause this crash?

Comment: [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]  does not allocate a new dictionary. Try ][NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10]; for example.

Comment: Did that ([[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];), same error...

Comment: Oh, sorry, your init has to call super init first and constructors have to return self.

Comment: Unbelievable!  I have never heard of doing that before, but then again, this is my first attempt at encapsulation!  Please re-write your comment as an answer so I can give you points and close this question... and thank you so much... I'm on  my way again... SD

Comment: @johnelemans Your first comment is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many issues here.

First off, do not declare public instance variables. Use properties and only for values that you want other classes to have access to.

```
@interface ExportBookData : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *booksArray;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *builtFileList;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *exportData;

- (id)initWithCategory: (NSString*) booksellerID;

@end
```

Now your `ExportBooksData init` method.

It needs to be:

```
-(id)initWithCategory: (NSString*) booksellerID  {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // do something with booksellerID
    }

    return self;
}
```

Every `init` method of a base class should following this general pattern.

And now your other code is needlessly using `->` operator. Use the actual properties provided by the interface instead:

```
ExportBookData *abe = [[ExportBookData alloc] initWithCategory:@"ABE"];
abe.builtFileList = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
abe.exportData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:booksArray.count];
```

But it makes no sense that external code is doing all of this. Let your class set itself up as needed. So now your `init` method should be:

```
-(id)initWithCategory: (NSString*) booksellerID  {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.builtFileList = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        self.exportData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:booksArray.count];

        // do something with booksellerID
    }

    return self;
}
```

Now your other code simply becomes:

```
ExportBookData *abe = [[ExportBookData alloc] initWithCategory:@"ABE"];
```

without the need to set the other properties.

There's a lot more you should be doing here (like making use of the `booksellerID` and `booksArray`) but this will get you started.

Comment: Hi Rick... thanks again... I always appreciate your help and clear explanations!  

If you don't mind, I'm going to give John the points because he was close, even tho' the first comment was wrong, and you have many points (not that you couldn't use more! :D ), but I just think it's the fair thing to do in this case.  If you don't agree, please comment before I mark John's as the answer.

Comment: Sure. You up vote any answer that you deem as helpful. It doesn't even have to be for your own question. If you happen to find a helpful answer when searching, up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor needs to call super init to be initialized correctly. Then you add the initialization code and finally return self;

```
  (id) initWithCategory: (NSString*) booksellerID
  {
      self = [super init];
      if (self != nil)
      {
          myBookSellerID = booksellerID;
      }
      return self;
  }
```